# Valid to calculate standard deviation from percentages?

Tags: standard-deviation, percentage

I'm writing a program that shows data about groups of entities. In each group, the entities make contributions to a goal. I'm interested in how even the contributions are distributed between the members of a group. So in each group I do the following: I normalize the number of contributions of each member by the sum of contributions within the group. What I get is, e.g:

Group 1:

| Members | Percentage of contributions |
| --- | --- |
| Member 1 | 33% |
| Member 2 | 33% |
| Member 3 | 34% |
| Member 4 | 0% |

My question is:
Is it valid to calculate the standard deviation of these percentages like so $\sqrt{\frac{(33-25)^2 + ... + (0 - 25)^2}{4}}$ and compare it with the standard deviation of other groups thus obtained or do I need to use the actual numbers of contributions for the calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It depends**: if all group sizes are equal, this standard deviation of normalized contributions is a fair comparison. However, if the group size is different, it will assign smaller numbers to groups with many members.

A very simple **example** that follows your own: Imagine, in group 1, the four members give $(10, 10, 10, 0)$, but group 2 has eight members giving $(10,10,10,10,10,10,0,0)$. Then the percentages in group 2 are half the percentages in group 1, and so is the standard deviation, but you would certainly say, that the variation in the two groups is the same.

A standard way to handle this is to use the [**coefficient of variation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation) (CV, also $c_V$) instead of the standard deviation. It is defined as the ratio of standard deviation to mean, so your calculation would be:
$$
c_V = \frac{\hat\sigma}{\hat\mu} =\sqrt{\frac{(33-25)^2 + ... + (0 - 25)^2}{4}}\bigg / 25,
$$
and for the group with eight members,
$$
c_V = \frac{\hat\sigma}{\hat\mu} =\sqrt{\frac{(16.7-12.5)^2 + ... + (0 - 12.5)^2}{8}}\bigg / 12.5.
$$
Another advantage of using this formula is, that it gives the same result if you apply it directly on the actual contribution amounts:
$$
c_V = \frac{\hat\sigma}{\hat\mu} =\sqrt{\frac{(33-25)^2 + ... + (0 - 25)^2}{4}}\bigg / 25 = \sqrt{\frac{(10-7.5)^2 + ... + (0 - 7.5)^2}{4}}\bigg / 7.5  
$$